# Show that a group is commutative if and only if another operation exists with certain properties

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Prove that a group $(G, \cdot )$ is commutative if and only if we can define on G another operation "$\circ$" such that: 
> i) $x \circ x = e$, for every $x \in G$ 
> ii) $x \circ (y \circ z)=(x \circ y) \cdot z $ for every $x,y,z \in G$

Attempt [from the comments]:

If we take $x=y=z$ we get $x \circ (x \circ x)=(x \circ x) \cdot x$ so $x \circ e = e \cdot x = x$. Taking $x=e$, $y=z=x$ we have $e \circ (x \circ x)=(e \circ x) \cdot x$, that is $e=(e \circ x) \cdot x$ so $(e \circ x)=x^{−1}$. And I think that's the way to go but I don't know how to continue.

[Edit] I have proved the second half:
If we take $ y=z$ we obtain : $x \circ (y \circ y)=(x \circ y) \cdot y,$ $\quad $so $\quad x = x \circ e =(x \circ y) \cdot y, \quad$  therefore $x \cdot y^{-1}= x \circ y$ $\quad (1)$

For x=y we get $x\circ (x\circ y) = (x \circ x) \cdot y=e \cdot y=y$ $\;$and from $(1)$ we have $x \circ (x\cdot y^{-1})=y \quad (2)$.
But $e \circ (y\cdot x^{-1})=(y\cdot x^{-1})^{-1}=x\cdot y^{-1} \quad$ so from $ (2): \; x\circ (e \circ (y\cdot x^{-1})) =y \quad $ so $ \quad (x \circ e) \cdot (y \cdot x^{-1})=y \;$ which is $\; x \cdot (y \cdot x^{-1}) =y \; $ and finally $xy=yx$ so G is commutative. But i still don't know how to do the other part.

Comment: Suppose such an operation exists. If we take $y = z$, and $x = e$, then using the first condition, it collapses to $e = (e \circ z) \cdot z$, i.e. the standard inverse of $z$ is $z^{-1} = e \circ z$. But then, taking $x = e$, and leaving $y$ and $z$ general, we get$$(y \circ z)^{-1} = e \circ (y \circ z) = (e \circ z) \cdot z = z^{-1} \cdot z = e.$$This implies $y \circ z = e^{-1} = e$, and this is true for any $y$ and $z$. But this contradicts (ii), assuming $G$ is non-trivial. I'm guessing that condition (ii) contains a typo?

Comment: it was wrong , sorry , i have written it right now

Comment: That makes more sense. Now, according to the site guidelines, we need you to provide some of your own thoughts and attempts in solving the question. Have you made any progress in either direction, i.e. either constructing $\circ$ from $\cdot$ given $\cdot$ is commutative, or in showing $\cdot$ is commutative given such an operation $\circ$? It doesn't matter if your attempts didn't go anywhere constructive. If you leave the question as is, it is likely to be closed (and has two close votes already, out of five).

Comment: if we take $x=y=z$  we get $x \circ ( x \circ x )=(x \circ x) \cdot x $ so $ x \circ e = e \cdot x =x$ . Taking $x=e, y=z=x $ we have $ e \circ (x \circ x)=(e \circ x) \cdot x $, that is $ e=(e \circ x) \cdot x $ so $ (e \circ x)=x^{-1} $. And i think that s the way to go but i dont know how to continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us suppose that such a $\circ$ exists. As you point out, $x \circ e = x$, and $e \circ x = x^{-1}$ (inverse, with respect to $\cdot$, of course). Thus,
$$(y \circ z)^{-1} = e \circ (y \circ z) = (e \circ y) \cdot z = y^{-1} \cdot z,$$
and so
$$y \circ z = (y^{-1} \cdot z)^{-1} = z^{-1} \cdot y. \tag{$\star$}$$
Now, (ii) becomes
\begin{align}
(y \circ z)^{-1} \cdot x = y^{-1} \cdot x \cdot z &\iff (z^{-1} \cdot y)^{-1} \cdot x = y^{-1} \cdot x \cdot z \\
&\iff y^{-1} \cdot z \cdot x = y^{-1} \cdot x \cdot z \\
&\iff z \cdot x = x \cdot z
\end{align}
Thus, $\cdot$ is commutative.

As for the other direction, $(\star)$ shows that $\circ$ is unique, if it exists, so we may use $(\star)$ instead as a definition. It's not difficult to show that $(\star)$ indeed satisfies (i) and (ii), if $z$ and $x$ are commutative (and indeed, the previous argument, followed backwards, shows (ii) holds).

Comment: oh you proved it too , thank you very much .

Comment: @MaishPetronas If you are satisfied with this answer, then you should upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for your support , I accepted it.